# Setting different height of an image in button control in all instances of the button control

Tags: wpf, button, user-controls

I have a wpf control that looks like this:

```
<Button x:Class="myProject.UI.Controls.MyButton" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="8" Background="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=BackgroundColor}">
            <DockPanel Margin="3">
                <Viewbox DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                    <Image Height="30" Source="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                </Viewbox>
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding Path=Content,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" FontSize="{Binding Path=FontSize,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="10,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <Image DockPanel.Dock="Right" Source="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Bmp}" Height="30" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0"></Image>
            </DockPanel>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

And when I use it in my view, here's what I write:

```
<controls:MyButton FontSize="24" Width="210" Height="60" Foreground="White" Tag="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Resources.backArrow}, Converter={StaticResource BitmapToImageSourceConverter}}" Content="{DynamicResource BackArrowButton}" Command="{Binding Path=GoToPreviousPage}" Margin="60 0 0 0">
    <Button.Resources>
        <Brush x:Key="BackgroundColor">#005BB5</Brush>
    </Button.Resources>
</controls:ImageButton>
```

The problem is that I have a few instances of this button in my project. In some of them, the height of the first image (in the viewbox) should be 30, and in some of them it needs to be 10.

How can I make the height of the first image to be set from each of the instances of the button? FOr example, like this:

```
<controls:MyButton **HeightOfTheFirstImage**="10" FontSize="24" Width="210" Height="60" Foreground="White" Tag="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Resources.backArrow}, Converter={StaticResource BitmapToImageSourceConverter}}" Content="{DynamicResource BackArrowButton}" Command="{Binding Path=GoToPreviousPage}" Margin="60 0 0 0">
    <Button.Resources>
        <Brush x:Key="BackgroundColor">#005BB5</Brush>
    </Button.Resources>
</controls:ImageButton>
```

Comment: I see this `myProject.UI.Controls.MyButton`, which means your Button has its own custom class, so you can always add some property such as called `FirstImageHeight`, then Bind the first Image's Height to that property. When using the Button, you can set that Property on demand.

Answer (score 0):

can try for the the viewbox height as Min. height...and the content to be stretch or so
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752301(v=vs.110).aspx

this might help.